# How to scan back and front sides of a check

Tags: android, sdk

I am developing a check capture application in android, by using an external SDK (A2iA) for the document/scan detection. As per the requirement I need to scan both sides of the check one after the other. Below is my code to scan the check.

```
if(scanFront == true) {
    side_check = "front";
    intent = new Intent(WebNative.this, DocumentDetectionActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(DocumentDetectionActivity.A2IA_COUNTRY_NAME, "US");
    intent.putExtra("abcd", side_check);
    startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}
```

When I click on the scan button the `DocumentDetectionActivity` from the SDK gets invoked and opens the detection screen. And I am able to print the logs also as below.

```
doc resultStatus OK
- Amount 5.00 (score 13)
- CAR 5.00 (score 12)
- Codeline 17021728.159213577.7417, (score 0)
- Payee Name  (score 0)
- Date Jan 6, 2030 (score 424)
```

After this I am able to see my activity itself, where I have the "scan" button. Now my requirement is, I need to scan the back side/2nd side of the check also without coming back to my activity. Could someone please help to call the `DocumentDetectionActivity` immediately, after the first side scan is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override your Activity's `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`. Inside this method, check that you just scanned the front of the check. If you did, start `DocumentDetectionActivity` the same way as you did in your question, but this time for the back side of the check.

See the official guide [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).